# What does initializing a string to {0, } do?

Tags: c, string, initialization

I've seen code like this:

```
char str[1024] = {0, };
```

and suspect that it is similar to doing this:

```
char str[1024];
str[0] = '\0';
```

But I couldn't find anything on it so I'm not sure.

**What is this (called) and what does it do?**

---

Disclaimer: I'm aware this might have been asked and answered before, but searching for `{0, }` is astonishingly hard. If you can point out a duplicate, I'll happily delete this question.

Comment: ```str[0]``` will be assigned to ```character``` 0 and rest 1022 elements will be assigned to ```'\0'```.

Comment: @Lucas interesting, because effectively that means all elements will be assigned the same value. I wonder why not just `{ 0 }` then?

Comment: That is a question for the original author.

Comment: @domsson Because ```0``` & ```\0``` has different character values. Although, there meaning is same which is equal to zero. First one is a character digit 0 and the second one is an escape character which denotes 0 or equivalent to 0 ```(aka Null Character)```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

This statement

```
char str[1024] = {0, };
```

initializes the first element to the given value `0`, and all other elements are to be initialized as if they have static storage, in this case, with a value `0`. Syntactically this is analogous to using

```
char str[1024] = {0};
```

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.7.9, p21

> *If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.*

and, from p10 (emphasis mine)

> *If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:*
>
> - *if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;*
> - ***if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;***
> - *if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;*
> - *if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;*

On the other hand

```
char str[1024];
str[0] = '\0';
```

only initializes the first element, and the remaining elements remains unitialized, containing indeterminate values.

Comment: ... which is vastly different than `str[0] = '\0'`, that null terminates the string and leaves everything else as garbage.

Comment: This is a very strange construct.  How did you know this?  Is it in the C specification somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is in the spec

Comment: In other words, `{ 0, }` is the same as `memset(&str, 0, 1024)`? Also, wouldn't `{ 0 }` achieve the exact same then?

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for asking "Would you like to take out the trash" instead of "Will you take out the trash."

Comment: I wasn't intending to require follow-up questioning, I just hadn't yet located the exact part of the standard before the initial response, but I was familiar with its existence.

Comment: Anyways, paragraphs 21 and 10 should cover what you're looking for.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Thanks, I added that to the answer itself, for anyone interested.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Would you mind adding a sentence on how the two alternatives given in my above comment fit into the picture, assuming that you know?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  `memset(&str, 0, 1024)` seems far more readable.

Comment: Interesting thing - the initialization is very inefficient if we consider the C strings initialized using the string literal. The garbage after the nul terminantor do not matter https://godbolt.org/z/H5HVUo

Comment: @domsson `memset(str, 0, 1024)` might not be the perfect example for replacement (depending on the type). using `{0}` is more apt.

Answer (score 2):

The `{0, }` initializer is the same as the more common `{0}` initializer.
The trailing comma is allowed by the syntax but it makes no difference.

[6.7.9--Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9):

```
      initializer:
               assignment-expression
               { initializer-list }
               { initializer-list , }
      initializer-list:
               designationopt initializer
               initializer-list , designationopt initializer
      designation:
             designator-list =
      designator-list:
             designator
             designator-list designator
      designator:
             [ constant-expression ]
             . identifier
```

The semantics are such that the `0`, which is syntactically required because at least one initializer-list item is syntactically required (it's a kind of a arbitrary requirement: compilers frequently support an empty `{}` as well) initializes the first subobject recursively ([6.7.9p17](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p17)):

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.148) In contrast, a designation causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject described by the designator. Initialization then continues forward in order, beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator.

and the rest is initialized as it would be *if the whole object had static storage duration* ([6.7.9p19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19),[6.7.9p21](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21)).  This practically means to `0` (as with `memset(,0,)` although with the caveat that paddings need not be initialized and that `0`-initialized pointers need not necessarily be "all-bits zero".

As far as I know, compilers on usual platforms (where pointers are all-bits-zero) just mostly do what they would do with `memset(,0,)`.

This "universal" zero initialization works because the first `0` will recursively hit a scalar type (number on pointer) which can be invariably initialized with the `0` initializer. The default "as-with-static-storage-duration" then initialization applies to the rest.

A perhaps slightly more interesting of the trailing initializer comma doing nothing would be:

```
int main()
{
    char one[]={0,}; //<the comma doesn't introduce another member
    _Static_assert(sizeof(one)==1,""); //holds
}
```

Comment: In other words, if you want to initialize a [char] array to all zeroes, just use `char str[1024] = {0};`.  Reading language specifications gives me such a headache.